# How to get a text area value in an Angular2 component with material design lite?

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I have a materiel design lite page with :

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <textarea name="categoryName" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="textAddCategory"></textarea>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="textAddCategory">categoryName</label>
        </div>
```

I am wondering how I could get the text area value in my component ...
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 4):

There are no of ways by using you can get value of textarea, i am using localvariable(`#`) here.

assuming you want value of textarea on some button click

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <textarea name="categoryName" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="textAddCategory" #textArea></textarea>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="textAddCategory">categoryName</label>
<button (click)='valueGetter(textArea.value)'>Submit</button>
            </div>


valueGetter(value){
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Angulars Reactive Forms approach and get the value with:

```
this.dataForm.get('textarea').value
```

Where *textarea* is the formControlName of your textarea and *dataForm* is the reference name of your FormGroup.

For more information on how to use Reactive Forms visit

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms